# PyQt - Keeping spacing at zero during window resize, grid layout

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4, qwidget, qtextedit, qgridlayout

I'm making an emacs-esque toy text editor.  At startup, there's one large window (a QTextEdit derivative) in the top center of the screen, with a minibuffer (QLineEdit derivative) underneath.  Both of the actual editing widgets are contained in the grids of parent classes called Window and MiniWindow (Window also keeps track of a QLabel that appears directly beneath the QTextEdit).

My Window object is at location 1, 1 in the grid, and my MiniWindow object is at 2, 1.  I've set content margins to 0 and spacing to 0, which looks great at first, but when I try to grow the window by dragging on the corner, this starts to happen:

[image: Gorg Editor Screenshot]

As you can see, the screen is divided into two rows (as it should be), but half of the vertical length of the screen is dedicated to each row. What I need is for the top Window to stretch its length during resizing so that it is always adjacent to the MiniWindow underneath.  Is there some other option I need to be setting?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, got it.

I was having this problem because the QLineEdit object was in the grid of my container class, MiniWindow. The height of a MiniWindow object is free to vary with the window resizing in a way that a QLineEdit alone would not be.  The fix was set to the maximumHeight of MiniWindow to approximately the height of a QLineEdit, which is around 16.

Works great now.